# Get id of hidden element's visible div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html contents as shown below,

```
<div class="ii" style="display:none">
    <div id ="dd1" class ="dd" style="display:block;">sss</div>
    <div id ="dd2" class ="dd" style="display:none;">www</div>
    <div id ="dd3" class ="dd" style="display:none;">222</div>
</div>
```

I need to get an element's id using jquery,

```
$(".ii").find(".dd:visible").attr('id');
```

if style for first div is display block , answer is getting.

pls check here also http://jsfiddle.net/jNLqA/41/ .

Comment: It wont work because <div class="ii" style="display:none"> is not visible. When you remove style="display:none" from it, it will work. Updated fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/jNLqA/47/

Comment: that's why i mentioned in question .. if style for first div is display block , answer is getting.

Answer (score 3):

here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/jNLqA/48/)**

```
alert($(".ii").find("div[style='display:block;']").attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 2):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jNLqA/46/)**

Because the parent of your element is not visible, so the element itself, is not visible too. You must use `.filter()` method:

```
var id = $(".ii .dd").filter(function () {
    if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
        return true;
    }
}).attr('id');

alert(id);
```

---

References:

- [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) - jQuery API Documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can't find an id of hidden element

```
<div class="ii" style="display:none"> is not visible
```

**But Still**

If you make it visible then you will surely get an `id`, See i have shown here to manipulate those cracks. [**fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jNLqA/49/)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with visibility css: http://jsfiddle.net/jNLqA/44/

```
visibility: hidden instead of display:none
```